# Evaluation of the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\sin\frac1n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, trigonometric-series

I am trying to evaluate the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1n\sin\dfrac1n$.

This was given in my real analysis test yesterday.

I have proved that the sum exists:

> We know for any non-negative real $x$, $\sin x\le x$.
>
> Hence $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1n\sin\dfrac1n\le
> \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1n\cdot\dfrac1n=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

But how can I find the sum?

Comment: I would be surprised if the sum would have a closed form. Are you content with a numerical result ?

Comment: Can't I have any closed form?

Comment: wolfram gives only an approximate value: sum_(n=1)^∞ sin(1/n)/n = 1.47283

Comment: Where does this show up? Why do you need / do you believe there is a closed form?

Comment: I'm asked to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ where $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1n\sin\frac1n$.

Comment: Thanks. In which course / which context?

Comment: Is it $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1n\sin\frac1n$ or $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k\sin\frac1k$ ?

Comment: This was given in my real analysis test yesterday.

Comment: @nbarto  oops! Sorry. It was $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ where $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k\sin\frac1k$.

Comment: Thanks. I added the info to your answer, it will help other users to estimate the difficulty of the question.

Comment: @nbarto Thanks! :)

Comment: To prove the sum exists, that is a good question for a real analysis test.  But to evaluate the sum, that would be **very surpising** for a real analysis test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot say there is no closed form, I just hope this gives you an idea.

\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\sin\frac1n&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\bigg[\frac1n-\frac1{3!n^3}+\frac1{5!n^5}-\frac1{7!n^7}+\cdots\bigg]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigg[\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{3!n^4}+\frac1{5!n^6}-\frac1{7!n^8}+\cdots\bigg]\\
&=\zeta(2)-\frac16\zeta(4)+\frac1{120}\zeta(6)-\frac1{5040}\zeta(8)+\cdots\end{align*}

When $k$ get large, $\zeta(k)$ will get closer and closer to $1$, I believe this gives a faster convergent to the sum.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of the sine function is wrong.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. Thank you.